# Is it possible to make DIV with inline-block to behave exactly like IMG with align=left?

Tags: html, css, valign

In the following example making DIV inline-block turns off valign effect. Is it possible to bring it back as with IMG in next row?

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td height="50" valign="top">

        <div style="display:inline-block; width:65px; height:40px; background-color: yellow; text-align: left;"></div>
        <input type="button" value="button">

         Some text

    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td height="50" valign="top">

        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="65" height="40" align="left" border="1">
        <input type="button" value="button">

         Some text

    </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to your `<div>`.

```html
<div style="display:inline-block; width:65px; height:40px; background-color: yellow; text-align: left;border: 1px solid black;vertical-align:top;"></div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/xvpYF/

HTML:

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td height="50" valign="top">
    <div style="display:inline-block; width:65px; height:40px; background-color: yellow; text-align: left;border: 1px solid black;vertical-align:top;"></div>
    <input type="button" value="button">
     Some text
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="50" valign="top">
    <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="65" height="40" align="left" border="1">
    <input type="button" value="button">
     Some text
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try putting it to float:left

http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/XDNe6/

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td height="50" valign="top">

        <div style="display:inline-block;float:left; width:65px; height:40px; background-color: yellow; text-align: left;"></div>
        <input type="button" value="button">

         Some text

    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td height="50" valign="top">

        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="65" height="40" align="left" border="1">
        <input type="button" value="button">

         Some text

    </td>
</tr>

</table>
```